# Collect columns with a specific date and total them

Tags: google-sheets

Using a google sheet to track all our tournaments that we're running. It's almost perfect, but I'm looking to get monthly recaps of our performance. Just looking for the formula that I can used with the dates, haven't been able to find anything anywhere. Any help would be great, thanks!

Image Here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXHRt.png

Comment: Share a sample sheet here or data as text table to your post. `QUERY()`, BYROW() & `AVERAGE()` with `FILTER()` all of these may work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a formula to get the average "Attendees" (column G) for January (using date on column D):

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(G:G; ARRAYFORMULA(MONTH(D:D)&YEAR(D:D)); "="&MONTH("1/1/2023")&YEAR("1/1/2023")); "---")
```

The IFERROR was added so that it displays "---" if there's no date for the given month

Don't forget to change the dates ""1/X/2023" for the different month. For example for "February", the formula would be:

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(G:G; ARRAYFORMULA(MONTH(D:D)&YEAR(D:D)); "="&MONTH("1/2/2023")&YEAR("1/2/2023")); "---")
```

For "Complete Teams" and "Incomplete Teams", you just have to replace by the correct column "H:H" and "I:I". For example for "Complete Teams"

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(H:H; ARRAYFORMULA(MONTH(D:D)&YEAR(D:D)); "="&MONTH("1/1/2023")&YEAR("1/1/2023")); "---")
```